# Multi Images Upload Issue

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

My HTML code is;

```
<form action="post_photo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
        <td class="trow1" width="10%">Select Image:</td>
        <td class="trow1" width="90%"><input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="trow2" align="left">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_post_photo" />
            <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="{$uid}" />
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Upload Photos" tabindex="2">
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

And my post_photo.php file has this code;

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
    foreach($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
    {
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];

        $ext = get_extension($_FILES['image']['name'][$key]);
        $allowed_ext = explode(",","png,gif,jpg,jpeg");
        if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_ext))
        {
            error("Invalid extension.");
        }

        if($file_size > 2097152)
        {
            error("File size must be less than 2 MB.");
        }       
        $file_name = "photo_".TIME_NOW.".".$ext;
        $insert_array = array(
            "uid" => $uid,
            "image" => $file_name,
            "approved" => '1',
            "likes" => '',
            "dateline" => time()
        );

        if(is_dir("uploads/photos/".$file_name)==false)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/photos/".$file_name);
        }
        $db->insert_query("photos", $insert_array);
    }
}
redirect("post_photo.php?action=post_photo", "Photos have been posted successfully.");
```

The issue is, if I select 4 images it upload 2 images to the ./uploads/photos/ folder. However it inserts 4 records in the `photos` sql table (which is correct since I selected 4 images) and all those records are correct too (I mean all those records have separate data for each image which is correct). And if I select 2 images then it uploads only one to ./uploads/photos/ folder however it inserts 2 records in sql table.

Why it is showing this issue? Please help!

Comment: check if(move_uploaded_file (......)) then execute sql query.

Comment: I've changed that part to this;
`if(is_dir("uploads/photos/".$file_name)==false)
   {
    $yes = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/photos/".$file_name);
   }
   
   if($yes)
   {
    $db->insert_query("photos", $insert_array);
   }`
But its still uploading 2 images and inserting 4 records in sql table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your PHP code to this;

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];

        $ext = get_extension($_FILES['image']['name'][$key]);
        $allowed_ext = explode(",","png,gif,jpg,jpeg");
        if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_ext))
        {
            error("Invalid extension.");
            continue;
        }

        if($file_size > 2097152)
        {
            $size_in_kb = $file_size/1000;
            error("File size must be less than 2MB.");
            continue;
        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/photos/".$tmp_name))
        {
            $insert_array = array("uid" => $uid,    "image" => $tmp_name,   "approved" => '1',  "likes" => '',  "dateline" => TIME_NOW);
            $db->insert_query("photos", $insert_array);
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
redirect("post_photo.php?action=post_photo", "Photos have been posted successfully.");
```

It should work!

Answer (score 0):

You said that 4 records are added to the db and only 2 images are uploaded.
Here's the problem:

```
    if(is_dir("uploads/photos/".$file_name)==false)
    {
        //1
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/photos/".$file_name);
    }
    //2
    $db->insert_query("photos", $insert_array);
```

As you can see, step //2 is always executed, but the step //1 is executed only if this condition is true: "is_dir("uploads/photos/".$file_name)==false".

**Solution**: Check if(move_uploaded_file (......)) before executing the sql statement.

Comment: I've changed that part to this;
`if(is_dir("uploads/photos/".$file_name)==false)
   {
    $yes = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/photos/".$file_name);
   }
   
   if($yes)
   {
    $db->insert_query("photos", $insert_array);
   }`
But its still uploading 2 images and inserting 4 records in sql table.

Comment: try this: $ok = false;
if(is_dir("uploads/photos/".$file_name)==false) { 
 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/photos/".$file_name); 
 $ok = true;
} 
if($ok === true) { 
 $db->insert_query("photos", $insert_array); 
}

Comment: No it does the same thing :(

Comment: Refresh your browser cache. It should work: $ok = false; if(is_dir("uploads/photos/".$file_name)!==true) { move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/photos/".$file_name); $ok = true; } if($ok === true) { $db->insert_query("photos", $insert_array); }

Comment: Pascut, its not browser's cache issue. Its PHP issue.

Comment: You should debug it, line by line to see where's the problem. Use a counter to see how many times the images are uploaded, or to see how many times the db insert is called. Use echo/print to see every time the results, use die(); to stop the problem exactly where you want.

Comment: If still doesn't work, please take a look at this tutorial: http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Multiple-File-Upload-with-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: I've tried many ways to achieve this but unfortunately none of them works. Please HELP!!